# How do I perform verification to get RealTime update for "notification"

Tags: getstream-io

This [getstream link](https://getstream.io/docs/?language=java#realtime-webhooks) says for verification of our webhook there are two ways.

In Verification via DNS,

- were do I have to place the "_getstream" TXT record?

Answer (score 0):

This would go in the domain record of your preferred domain name where you host your webhook. For example, if we would connect to `your-awesome-webhook-service.com` as the hostname, then you would add the TXT record as an extra record with your `A` records, `CNAME` records, etc. at name.com or wherever you control your DNS entries for that domain.